# Responsive bootstrap not working properly

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

**EDIT==============================================================================**

[Nick R](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2470724/nick-r) says that its not working because of the responsive design, and its TRUE. Things are working after i change the css to the default (not responsive) one.

However, i have a new question :

This quote is taken from bootstrap official web :

> The fluid grid system uses percents instead of pixels for column
>   widths. It has the same responsive capabilities as our fixed grid
>   system, ensuring proper proportions for key screen resolutions and
>   devices.

So, is it means that the `row-fluid` class is already responsive (adaptive to screen size) so i dont need to use the responsive css?

Thanks :D

**EDIT==============================================================================**

I try to implement bootstrap library in my project, i want to use its responsive layout.

However, the bootsrap only working in the **design** tab. Please take a look at the following screenshot :

[image]

However, this is what i got in the browser simulator :

[image]

This is my full (but very simple) code :

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>JakartaWikiMall</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0">
    <!--<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">-->
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/favicon.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="images/apple-touch-icon.png">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap-responsive.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/JakartaWikiMall.css">
    <script>
        window.$ = window.jQuery = WLJQ;
        $("#btnPromo").click(function(){
            $("#pagePort").load("pages/MainPage.html", function(){
                alert("loaded!");
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body onload="WL.Client.init({})" id="content" style="display: none;">
    <!--application UI goes here-->
    <div data-role="page" id="pagePort">
        <div data-role="content">
            <div class="span9">
                <div class="row-fluid">
                    <div class="span1">test1</div>
                    <div class="span1">test2</div>
                    <div class="span1">test3</div>
                </div>
                <div class="row-fluid">
                    <div class="span1">test4</div>
                    <div class="span1">test5</div>
                    <div class="span1">test6</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script src="js/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/initOptions.js"></script>
    <script src="js/JakartaWikiMall.js"></script>
    <script src="js/messages.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

How to make the bootstrap working?

Any help is appreciated, just let me know if you need something and thanks for your time :D

Comment: You have `bootstrap-responsive.min.css` included in the project, so it's responsive, and adapting the layout according to the screen size.

Comment: @NickR yes you are probably right, because its not working when i change my display perspective to phone (iPhone 4 for example). However, i think because of its responsiveness, it should be working because it will change its size depend on the phone screen.

Comment: @NickR Do you have any suggestion, what should i do to make things working? Thanks for your help :D

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML markup is wrong, you're lacking the `.container` or `.container-fluid` class, and you have to keep in mind the Bootstrap grid system. It's a common confusion to think `"I want 3 columns so the sum has to be 1+1+1"` but in fact Bootstrap uses a 12 grid system (unless customized), so for 3 equal width columns like in your case, you would need **4+4+4**. Thus, your code should look like this:

```
<div data-role="page" id="pagePort">
    <div data-role="content">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row-fluid">
                <div class="span4">test1</div>
                <div class="span4">test2</div>
                <div class="span4">test3</div>
            </div>
            <div class="row-fluid">
                <div class="span4">test4</div>
                <div class="span4">test5</div>
                <div class="span4">test6</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[See fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/zfrzcq84/)

**Note:** I realize this is an old question but was showing at first page for me, so asking it just in case the answer is still needed for someone